# Error cuando importo los Standard Assets de unity, 'GUIText' is obsolete: 'GUIText has been removed. Use UI.Text instead.'

Tags: c#, unity3d

El código de error es el siguiente:

```
Assets\Standard Assets\Utility\SimpleActivatorMenu.cs(10,16): error CS0619: 'GUIText' is obsolete: 'GUIText has been removed. Use UI.Text instead.'
```

Creo yo que es por la versión de unity, pero no se por qué otro componente debo cambiarlo.

Comment: En desarrollo cuando una clase está marcada como obsoleta significa que en las siguientes versiones ya no existirá esa clase y normalmente el lenguaje de programación/framework proporciona el nombre de la clase que la reemplazará recomendando su uso, que en tu caso sería UI.Text

Comment: El problema es que no me permite ejecutar el juego

Comment: No te dejará compilar porque es un error efectivamente, cámbialo por el componente UI.Text

Comment: Creo que no me dia a entender, pido disculpas, lo que no sé es a que tipo de componente UI.Text debo cambiar, por ejemplo un GUITexture lo cambié por un Texture2D, de antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

este problema lo he resuelto de forma simples.
Lo primero que tienes que hacer es irte a Unity y clicar en console, te va mostrar los errores que tienes, haz doble click en el error y lo abres con un editor de codigo (yo utilize el sublimetest) te va mostar el codigo ahy lo que tienes que hacer es sutituir lo siguente. Donde dice añadir  y cambiar codigo.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI; //<----AÑADIR CODIGO

#pragma warning disable 618
namespace UnityStandardAssets.Utility
{
    public class SimpleActivatorMenu : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // An incredibly simple menu which, when given references
        // to gameobjects in the scene
        public Text camSwitchButton; //<---CAMBIAR CODIGO 
        public GameObject[] objects;
```